# Where I can download financial & technical data for graphs of bachelor thesis?

Tags: charts, finance, live-data

I'm writing bachelor thesis and I have to do some graphs. I think that I can take snapshot, but it isn't good idea. Can I somewhere download historical data about Bitcoin?

EDIT. I need technical data like there: https://blockchain.info/charts + financial data like USD/BTC etc. for create graphs. I can't use screenshots for bachelor thesis...

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of data are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[Bitcoinchain.com](http://bitcoinchain.com/export) allows you to export market data. You can use that to create graphs for the historic exchange rate.

If you could be more specific which graphs you want to create, one would be able to point out sources for the respective data. I don't think anyone is interested in searching the source data for all of the charts on blockchain.info, while you were only going to use one or two.